# hibernate one-to-many updating skipped uniqueConstraints checking

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a project where I need to save a download file information with keywords.
Typical one-to-many scenario, right? A download record to many download-keyword relationship records.

So here is what the Download.java look like

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "downloads", catalog = "nbpx")
public class Download extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
public Integer downloadId;
public String title;
public Set<DownloadKeyword> downloadKeywords = new HashSet<DownloadKeyword>(
        0);
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "downloadId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getDownloadId() {
    return downloadId;
}


public void setDownloadId(Integer downloadId) {
    this.downloadId = downloadId;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "download")
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
public Set<DownloadKeyword> getDownloadKeywords() {
    return downloadKeywords;
}

public void setDownloadKeywords(Set<DownloadKeyword> downloadKeywords) {
    this.downloadKeywords = downloadKeywords;
}
    }
```

Since I don't want any duplicate download-keyword relation records in the table, I set a JPA unique Constraints for the class. But I didn't use a composite key. And this is what DownloadKeyword.java look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "downloadkeywords", catalog = "nbpx", uniqueConstraints =
       @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"keywordId", "downloadId" }))
public class DownloadKeyword extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Integer downloadKeywordId;
public Download download;
public Integer keywordId;
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "downloadKeywordId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getDownloadKeywordId() {
    return downloadKeywordId;
}

public void setDownloadKeywordId(Integer downloadKeywordId) {
    this.downloadKeywordId = downloadKeywordId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "downloadId", nullable = false, insertable=true)
public Download getDownload() {
    return download;
}

public void setDownload(Download download) {
    this.download = download;
}

public Integer getKeywordId() {
    return keywordId;
}

public void setKeywordId(Integer keywordId) {
    this.keywordId = keywordId;
}
}
```

When I save a download entity, I expect to see all the download-keyword relationship entities are saved within the download entity save session. And I need to avoid duplication in download-keyword relationship table. But every time I save it, the relation records were inserted straightly into DB without checking the duplication with JPA annotation.

So here is my question: Did multiple-column uniqueConstraints of JPA annotation get ignored when entities were saving in one-to-many save or update session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **uniqueConstraints** are only for table generation support.
See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#uniqueConstraints).

Since you're already using `Set<DownloadKeyword>` in the **Download** class - you can implement **hashCode** and **equals** methods in the **DownloadKeyword** class (include primary key **downloadKeywordId** and the **keywordId** properties)  to accomplish what you want.

However, I would still prefer a composite key approach.